# Ajax returns GET request instead of POST

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create a personal messaging system in laravel, and apart of this system is being able to send messages in a form without refreshing the entire page.

I've been following some youtube tutorials, and this is the Ajax script I have so far.

```
<form id="form{{$dm->id}}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input id="message" placeholder="Send a message" style="border-radius: 0px;" type="username" class="form-control" name="message">
                    <script>
                    $('form{{$dm->id}}').ready(function (){
                        
                    $('form{{$dm->id}}').on('submit', function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: '{{ route("sendMessage", $dm->id) }}',
                            data: $('form{{$dm->id}}').serialize(), 
                            success: function(response){
                                alert('suces')
                            },
                            error: function(response){
                               alert('failure')
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    });
                    </script>
                </form>
```

Instead of sending a POST request to the controller, it sends a GET request and just redirects.
This is my first time messing with Ajax/Javascript in general, so I don't know exactly why this isn't working.

Controller script:

```
public function sendM(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'message' => 'required|string|max:255|min:4',
    ]);
    
    $dm = Dm::find($id);
    $mess = new Message;
    $mess->Authid = Auth::user()->id;
    $mess->Userid = $dm->Userid;
    $mess->Dmid = $dm->id;
    $mess->message = $request->input('message');
    $dm->messages()->save($mess);
    $dm->touch();
}
```

Route entry:

```
Route::post('/sendmessage/id{id}', 'SettingsController@sendM')->name('sendMessage')->middleware('verified');
```

Any help is very much appreciated! (Note: Sorry if it is something really obvious)

Comment: add: method: 'POST',

Comment: What is the full context of the javascript? Are you certain this is the call being executed? Can you console.log('start') right before $.ajax and console.log('finish') after, and only see 'start' in the browser console? What happens if you view the developer tool network tab with 'preserve history' checked - does the network activity match what you would expect? Are there any unexpected redirects?

Comment: When I added the `console.log('start')` and `console.log('finish')` in the script, it didn't seem to log anything. In the network tab it is only redirecting to a GET address with the information, not an actual POST request.

Answer (score 0):

In the $.ajax call, you need to set the method to post instead of the type.

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '{{ route("sendMessage", $dm->id) }}',
        data: $('form{{$dm->id}}').serialize(), 
        success: function(response){
          alert('suces')
        },
        error: function(response){
        alert('failure')
        }
       });
```

As an aside, jquery is often considered to be on the way out. You may want to look into what some alternatives to jquery would look like, such as vue.js or react. Specific to the ajax aspect, Laravel has built in axios support.

Comment: You make a good point about jquery. I will look into Vue/React, and see what they both offer. If you don't mind me asking, what is axios?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it solves your problem, but you must also add the csrf token to the headers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});
```

(if the token is in a meta tag of course)

Comment: I've tried adding headers, but it is still the same result every time.

Comment: I didn't think it would solve your problem, but they do need to be added anyway.

Answer (score 0):

An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

```
             <form id="form{{$dm->id}}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input id="message" placeholder="Send a message" style="border-radius: 0px;" type="username" class="form-control" name="message">
                    <script>
                    $('form{{$dm->id}}').ready(function (){
                        
                    $('form{{$dm->id}}').on('submit', function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST', //Check your JQ version.
                            method: 'POST', //Check your JQ version.
                            contentType:"multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8",
                            //url: '{{ route("sendMessage", $dm->id) }}',
                            url: '{{ route("sendmessage", $dm->id) }}',
                            data: $('form{{$dm->id}}').serialize(), 
                            success: function(response){
                                alert('suces')
                            },
                            error: function(response){
                               alert('failure')
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    });
                    </script>
                </form>
```

Comment: I've tried both `type` and `method`, none are working unfortunately.

Comment: try add contentType:"multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8"

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. It is all just the same result.

Comment: check your route is '{{ route("sendMessage", $dm->id) }}' or '{{ route("sendMessage/", $dm->id) }}'    ?
in your serverSide is: Route::post('/sendmessage/id{id}' with / between sendmessage and id ?

Comment: i observed too that in javascript you call: sendMessage > Message with M with upperCaser but in your server side Route::post('/sendmessage/id{id}', message start with m lowercase.?

Comment: @toto their route name is with a capital M, so that should be correct

Comment: I'm pretty sure the route is correct, as I am using the route name, not the actual address. But I guess I could be wrong.

Comment: The $.ajax not is the problem. Can you check in your console developer of browser and check the header and method and URL request.

Comment: It is redirecting to a GET method with the token information and the actual message behind a ?. `(Ex. https:/web.com/all/users?_token=IxkDOgME8VbC4KzpqYK29g7xp2uCxOkYMz8rhD2W&message=ehehe)`

Comment: The redirection is from your server side. Route configuration.